# Bundle creating directories in working directory when bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Whenever I run `bundle install` in my rails app, an empty folder is created in the app's root directory, which looks like this:

```
bundler20140929-26466-x86kd5
bundler20140929-30110-rbes8h
bundler20141010-54137-1g4prq1
```

**UPDATE:**

All of my other apps have to same problem, so it must be environment related. Also, I see RackMultipart upload files from carrierwave. Thinking this was related to a TMP variable not being set I tried adding this to development.rb:

```
ENV['TMPDIR'] = Rails.root.join('tmp')
ENV['TMP'] = Rails.root.join('tmp')
ENV['TEMP'] = Rails.root.join('tmp')
```

But the problem persists..

Any ideas about why might this be happening?

Comment: Which version of bundler are you using ? Try to re-install it.

Comment: So, more detail may be necessary. I'm running this app alongside others in a vagrant box, and every app has this problem, so my thinking is that it must be environmental.